# How to send json data elastic search get request url

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

Following works fine

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "chicag*",
      "fields"  : ["name"],
      "_name":"myqry"
    }
  }
}
'
```

How can I create a  browser url for  this  GET  request ?   I URLEncoded the  json and  tried -

localhost:9200/_search?data=%7B%0A%20%20%22query%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22query_string%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22query%22%20%3A%20%22chicag%2A%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22fields%22%20%20%3A%20%5B%22name%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_name%22%3A%22Chcagoooo%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D

but it did not  work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to [send your DSL query as a query string parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string) using the `source` parameter like this:

```
localhost:9200/_search?pretty&source={"query":{"query_string":{"query":"chicag*","fields":["name"],"_name":"myqry"}}}&source_content_type=application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using multi-get API `_mget`. In my case, I am using the following URL to get all the documents in the specified range.
Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docs-multi-get.html#mget-ids

This example displays documents with id 49 and 50.

`http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mget?pretty&source={ "ids" : [49, 50] }&source_content_type=application/json`